# I need a ":After" xpath, if iry to more xpath.. but it not find the drowndown icon... i want to select the dropdown

Tags: xpath, icons, dropdown, salesforce-lightning, browser-automation

[xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1yAt.png)
i want to select the dropdown icon.. if i inspect it highlights on the "::after" line..so any one please tell the xpath.. for my click operation

any one suggest after :: operation in xpath

i will more locators also..like css selector..."#brandBand_2 > div > div > div > div > app_flexipage-lwc-app-flexipage > app_flexipage-lwc-app-flexipage-decorator > slot > app_flexipage-lwc-app-flexipage-internal > forcegenerated-adg-rollup_component___force-generated__flexipage_-app-page___-invoices > forcegenerated-flexipage_invoices__js > flexipage-lwc-default-app-home-template > div > div > slot > flexipage-component2:nth-child(1) > slot > c-customer-invoices > div > c-customer-invoice-table > div > div > c-customer-invoice-header > div > div > div.slds-page-header__controls.slds-grid_vertical-align-center.flex-wrap > div.ml-1.my-1.custom-search-dropdown.customer-select.customer-filter > div > span.dynamic-value:after"

but it not evluvate